# How to convert each items of list into a dictionary?

Tags: python, django

Here I have a list like this.

```
ls = ['Small:u', 'Small:o']
```

What I want is to create a dictionary of each list items like this.

```
dict1 = {'Small':'u'}
dict2 = {'Small':'o'}
```

How can I do it ? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
>>> x = [dict([pair.split(":", 1)]) for pair in ['Small:u', 'Small:o']]
>>> x
[{'Small': 'u'}, {'Small': 'o'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, but one thing I'm not sure whether is possible (or a good idea at all) is to programmatically assign variable names to new dictionaries, so instead the easier way is to create a dictionary of dictionaries:

```
dic_of_dics = {}
for index, item in enumerate(ls):
    i, j = item.split(':')
    dic_of_dics[f'dict{index}'] = {i : j}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another way:

```
ls = ['Small:u', 'Small:o']
dict_list = []
for i in ls:
    k, v = i.split(':')
    dict_list.append({k: v})

print(dict_list)
print(dict_list[1].values())
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps with minimal line:

```
ls = ['Small:u', 'Small:o']
dict_list = map(lambda x:dict([x.split(':')]), ls)
# for python3: print(list(dict_list))
# for Python2: print(dict_list)
```

Explanation: I am using `map` function to convert the list of string to list of lists. Then I am passing it through `dict`(to convert them to dictionary).

Comment: Did you run this? This will result in `{"Small": "o"}`.

Comment: Oops. I have updated the answer. Thanks. I was assuming first value of the string(before `:`) was unique.